# Appending new values to a list from a text file

Tags: python, list, replace, position, append

Hey so its my first post and I'm extremely new to python/coding.
I have this problem and I'm not quite sure how to explain it.
Essentially I have this txt file with a bunch of rows full of "lists of characters/numbers"
like "5, 0, 10, " and "$, 20, , 5" and I have a block of code which basically goes through each element in each row and returns 0 for blank spaces and -1 for non-digits, if the element is a digit it simply returns the digit. NOW, the problem is I have to now somehow edit those rows of numbers and replace the blank spaces and non-digits with the returned values (0 and -1), and then spit it out in python and frankly im too much of a coding noob to know what functions to use. I have this mind block, I know exactly what I need to do but I have no idea how to go about doing it. I need to somehow append those returned values into a list with the original digits, minus the blank spaces and non-digits and in their position have 0's and -1's. Sorry again this is my first post and its probably formatted horribly, scratch that it IS formatted horribly.

```
def parseVote(s):
    s = s.strip()
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    elif s.isdigit() == True:
        return s
    else:
        return -1

print(parseVote())
```

Comment: Paste your code in the post here so we can have a look and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Edited my post and added code

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what will meet your requirements. This may be a longer method than what would be possible using the strip function, but I thought I'd go for simplicity. The main thing is the loop through the list of lists, and a nested loop for each element in each list. I'm noticing however that you get the same result if the digit is 0 (result 0) as when the element is blank (result 0). Might be a problem.

```
with open( r'C:\Program Files\s.txt' ) as s_file:
    s = []
    for line in s_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip('\n')
        s.append( stripped_line.split(',') )

s_file.close( )
#s = [['5','0','10'],['$','20','','5']]

def parseVote(s):

    new_s = []        
    for s_list in s: 

        s_transform = []                
        for elem in s_list:

            if len(elem) == 0:
                s_transform.append( 0 )            
            elif elem.isdigit( ) == True:
                s_transform.append( elem )            
            else:
                s_transform.append( -1 )

        new_s.append( s_transform )

    return new_s

new_s = parseVote(s)
print(new_s)
```

**Output:**

```
[['5', '0', '10'], [-1, '20', 0, '5']]
```

Comment: Wow your block of code is actually so readable, its like reading a book ahahaha the more I learn about coding the more it interests me, thank you so much for helping me, I will definitely implement this and see if it works, I think I just need to import the txt file. Again thank you this really helps.

Comment: @Jack Jock. I edited the code block with a way to import a comma delimited text file with row instances.